# Bootstrap dropdown - changing display property of menu items

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, angular, drop-down-menu

I am using Bootstrap  dropdown menu with angular. I want to make some menu items visible and invisible using  the display property. Class hidden_item is  defined as display:none.  When the user logs in,  it does show the "Messages" menu item but clicking on it does not show Inbox and Sent links.   Later if I refresh the page, everything works  as expected and Inbox and Sent become visible.  How can I make it work without refreshing the page?

```
                <li  [ngClass]="isLoggedIn() ? 'dropdown' : 'hidden_item'">
                    <a  [routerLink]="['Mailbox', {'boxname': 'inbox'}]" class="dropdown-toggle">Messages <span class="nav-up-carret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a [routerLink]="['Mailbox', {'boxname': 'inbox'}]">Inbox</a> </li>
                        <li><a [routerLink]="['Mailbox', {'boxname': 'sent'}]">Sent</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use *ngIf and try it this way:

```
li  *ngIf="isLogedIn()">
       <a  [routerLink]="['Mailbox', {'boxname': 'inbox'}]" class="dropdown-toggle">Messages <span class="nav-up-carret"></span>
      </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                  <li><a [routerLink]="['Mailbox', {'boxname': 'inbox'}]">Inbox</a> </li>
                  <li><a [routerLink]="['Mailbox', {'boxname': 'sent'}]">Sent</a></li>
            </ul>
</li>
```

This way, angular will automatically remove the block from the dom if `isLogedIn()` returns `false` but will add it if it returns `true`.

Comment: Tried it  but clicking on Messages still does not show Inbox and Sent

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly, you are missing a `data-toggle="dropdown"` property in your 'Messages' anchor element.

It should be

```
<li  [ngClass]="isLogedIn() ? 'dropdown' : 'hidden_item'">
                    <a  [routerLink]="['Mailbox', {'boxname': 'inbox'}]" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Messages <span class="nav-up-carret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a [routerLink]="['Mailbox', {'boxname': 'inbox'}]">Inbox</a> </li>
                        <li><a [routerLink]="['Mailbox', {'boxname': 'sent'}]">Sent</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
```

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: i have noticed one problem, if I refresh the page, inbox and sent link disappear. I have to close the browser and login again to see  those  links again

Comment: Disappear in the sense? Even the `Messages` link also gone?

Comment: message link remains but Inbox and Sent links are gone